# Neural network Perceptron algorithm Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, perceptron

I want to optimize the weights by different algorithms like adam; stochastic gradient descent etc and try different activation function using a perceptron of sklearn as below:

I did not found in sklearn how to do that any suggestion ???

```
Perceptron(alpha=0.0001, class_weight=None, eta0=1.0, fit_intercept=True,
      max_iter=10, n_iter=None, n_jobs=1, penalty=None, random_state=42,
      shuffle=True, tol=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Perceptron()` is equivalent to `SGDClassifier(loss=”perceptron”, eta0=1, learning_rate=”constant”, penalty=None)` so is using SGD by design.

What you're looking for is I think [`sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html)

Comment: tHANKS FOR YOU QUICK ANSWER BY THE WAY I AM LOOKING TO USE A SIMPLE PERCEPTRON BUT I WANNA USE DIFFERENT ALGORITHMS TO OPTIMIZE PERCEPTRON WEIGHTS IN SKLEARN I DIDN4T FIND HOW FOR THIS I ASKED THE QUESTION